# How queues and threading work?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

This is related to the Grand Central Dispatch API used in objective-c, with the following codes:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("other queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    ....some functions that retrieves data from server...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"got it");
    });
});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

My current understanding of how queues work is that the blocks in a queue will go on a thread for that queue. So two queues will become two threads. With multi-threading, those two queues will happen simultaneously. 
However, the "got it" appears right at when the program received the data. How did that happen?

Please point out if you want to correct or add to my understanding of threading and queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So two queues will become two threads.

Not necessarily. One of the advantages of GCD is that the system dynamically decides how many threads it creates, depending on the number of available CPU cores and other factors. It might well be that two custom queues are executed on the same background thread, especially if there are rarely tasks for both queues waiting to be executed.

The only thing you can be certain about is that a serial queue never uses more than one thread at the same time. So the tasks you add to the same (serial) queue will always be executed in order. This is not the case for the three concurrent global queues you get with `dispatch_get_global_queue()`.

Additionally, the main queue (the one you access with `dispatch_get_main_queue()`) is always bound to the main thread. It is the only queue whose tasks are executed on the program's main thread.

In your example, the task for the `downloadQueue` gets executed on a background thread. As soon as the code reaches `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`, GCD pushes this new task to the main thread where it gets executed practically immediately provided that the main thread is not busy with other things.

Comment: “It is the only queue whose tasks are *guaranteed to be* executed on the program's main thread.” dispatch_sync() from the main thread to another queue will often be executed without creating another thread of execution, i.e. on the main thread.

Comment: @OleBegemann, If the program runs on the iPhone which has a single core. Would there be a conclusive relationship between number of threads and number of queues?

Comment: @William: that's an implementation detail that you shouldn't care about. Apple could change it at any time and by the way, not all iPhones are single core (the iPhone 4S has a dual core chip). It is likely that the smaller the number of cores, the fewer threads GCD will create. But that's probably not the only influencing variable.